# Two themes in Angular. Problem with variable in SCSS

Tags: css, angular, variables, sass, frontend

I try to realise two theme in Angular 10 by this [flow](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dark-mode-with-angular-and-css-variables?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css). It works only with css. I use SCSS in my project. How can I modify this example to use scss? Sorry that I don't have any code here. Code you can find it in link. Thanks for help!

Comment: What specific issues are you having with SCSS? CSS is valid SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to specify you are using SCSS on your project.](https://dev.to/stefaniefluin/how-to-structure-scss-in-an-angular-app-3376)

You can manually change your angular.json file like so:

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "style": "scss"
    }
},
```

And then change your files from CSS to SCSS, including the main styles.css referenced in the angular.json.

Comment: How it will decide my problem? My broblem is with variable in SCSS. I use SCSS in my 4 in my project. I need to customisate this example with variable in SCSS. Because There are no variable such in css.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `app.component.css` file to `app.component.scss` and in app.component.ts change the `styleUrls` to `app.component.scss`

Comment: How it will decide my problem? My broblem is with variable in SCSS. I use SCSS in my SCSS in my project. I need to customisate thix exemple with variable in SCSS. Because There are no variable such in css.